# Prevent double submit with a4j:commandButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, richfaces

We have a form which has a submit button (input type="submit") and a bunch of a4j:commandButtons which are ajax buttons that translate into input type="button".

I'm able to use this jquery code to prevent double submitting of the submit button:

```
         $('#createPostingForm').submit(function(){
          $(':submit').click(function() {  
                 return false;  
          });
        });
```

But how can I also disable the a4j:commandButtons from being submitted more than once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Ended up adding these attributes to the a4j:commandButton:

```
onclick="this.disabled=true" oncomplete="this.disabled=false"
```