# jsf commandbutton setenabled onclick

Tags: javascript, jsf, onclick, commandbutton

how can I disable a commandbutton (ajaxbutton) when the user clicks on it?

i tried it with:

```
onclick="javascript:this.disabled='true';"
```

and

```
onclick="document.getElementById('buttonid').disabled='true'"
```

but nothing works?

Comment: Can you show some HTML too? You don't need to prefix your script with `javascript:` inside an `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific problem I think you just need to remove the quotes around 'true'.
But also look at this link [How can I disable an h:commandButton without preventing the action and actionListener from being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744597/how-can-i-disable-an-hcommandbutton-without-preventing-the-action-and-actionlis)