# JSF Button disabling not works when is in form

Tags: jsf

I want when user entered some value in text field and submit, the button should disabled.

But it just disabled when button is not in a form:

Works

```
<h:inputText/>
<h:commandButton value="btn1" action="#{bean2.showClicked}" onclick="this.disabled=true;" />
```

Not works

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText/>
    <h:commandButton value="btn1" action="#{bean2.showClicked}" onclick="this.disabled=true;" />
</h:form>
```

I need to disable button in form.

Comment: Both of those work for me. Using Java EE 6 deployed to Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

Comment: @DavidS I using java EE7 with Tomcat.

Comment: HTML/JavaScript are unrelated to Java EE. Besides, Tomcat is not an application server. It is a bare-bones Servlet container having Servlets/JSP APIs only  -- not a Java EE compliant container.

Comment: @Tiny Why in the second case it cannot disable the button?

Comment: Maybe he meant TomEE.

Comment: The button is permanently disabled and no request is sent after disabling the button I could see, when I ran your example (the second one). This can never be a requirement by the way.

Comment: You need to set an interval. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11746851/1391249). All in all, you want to prevent duplicate form submits I guess. You already use PrimeFaces. There are several ways to do so. Why not choose one of them -- what you need?

Comment: @Tiny I tried suggested link solution, but not worked for me!

Comment: 'not worked for me'  is not 'smart'... Mention what you experienced from a **developer** point of view. So things like server crashed and stopped working, ajax call not send, whatever...

Comment: Use a local valiable to enable disable the button, on action method change it's value. And use **disabled** attribute to enable disable it.